# Kafka Magic Tool for Mac M1

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apple-m1

I want to use docker run -d --rm -p 8888:80 digitsy/kafka-magic to check some topics. Unfortunately it does not support Mac M1 processors. Is there an image for M1 processors?

Comment: Voting to close as asking for off site resources. You should contact the developer directly https://www.kafkamagic.com/feedback/ or use a different tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Kafka Magic does support the Apple M1 processor

Comment: this answer could be improved by linking to official writing that confirms the claim

Comment: Here:
https://www.kafkamagic.com/download/